# Cannot generate HashKey for facebook app

Tags: android, facebook

Hi everybody I have been working on this issiue for hours .Basicly  I need to get Key Hashes for creating android-facebook apps.I couldnt find any jdk folder
Although I have adt(is that ok?by the way) Thats way I had to download jdk1.7 This is the JDK path

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin
```

then  I have downloaded  openssl from Google code and renamed it as OpenSSL and located that folder inside " C:\" here

and this my command

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin> keytool -exportcert -alias
 androiddebugkey -keystore "C:Users\age\.android\debug.keystore" |
 "C:\OpenSSL" sha1 -binary |"C:OpenSSL" base64
```

but Its not working  "couldnt find......."
I think there is something wrong here
C:OpenSSL" base64
Because there is no base64 stuff inside OpenSSL folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code to create Hash code, which you can view in Log.

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("Your Package Name",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.i("KeyHash:",
                    "KeyHash: "
                            + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
                                    Base64.DEFAULT));

        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.i("KeyHash !!!!!!!:", e.getMessage());

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.i("KeyHash $$$$$$$:", e.getMessage());
    }
```

OR

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "D:\Projects\XYZ\keystore" | "C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\openssl" base64
```

Note: For this you need to install OpenSSL (http://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric53/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.gemfire.7.0/gemfire_nativeclient/security/1downloadinstallopenssl.html)

Answer (score 2):

In oreder to make facebook integration with your app, you have to generate the hask key.
Go through following steps to generate hash key.

**steps**

1. download zip file of OPEN-SSL.*(https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/list)*(jdk/bin/debug.keysore file not allowed so don't consider it.you have to consider this file from OPEN_SSL).
2. extract this zip file to your C drive in any folder or (make new folder names SSL).
3. open that extracted folder and you can see another threww folder inside it.

   i)bin    ii) include    iii) lib
4. now open bin folder
5. press ***SHIFT* + Righclick** ,you show like this.
   [image]
6. now press "Open Command Window Here"
7. Command Prompt will be apper on sceen , now paste below code to your Command Prompt.
    for window..

   `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

and for linux..

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

8. now hash key will be show in your command prompt
9. right click in command prompt and click mark option.
10. select the hash  key by using arrow key.
11. press ctrl+c (copy)
12. now paste this hash key where